# What is the InterCheck process that occasionally uses 96% CPU on my Mac?

Tags: macos, cpu

I heard my computer's fan spinning fast, so I checked Activity Monitor and saw that a process called InterCheck was using close to 96% CPU. What is this process and why's it using so much CPU?

In the Inspect window, it said that the parent process is launchd.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's a real-time scanning process by **[Sophos Anti-Virus](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-mac-home-edition.aspx)** that scans your computer's running processes in the background.

The parent process is `launchd` so that when you accidentally kill the `Intercheck` process, it gets restarted.

Comment: Sophos has a utility that lets you look at the various logs that might cause Sophos to misbehave and use all of your processor. Take a look at it here: https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/33533.aspx#macgeneral It might be useful for the next time InterCheck acts out.

Comment: If anyone wants to temporarily disable it, go to Preferences, then the "On-Access" tab (far left), and turn the on-access scanner off. If this setting is greyed out, you'll need to unlock this panel by clicking the lock in the lower-left corner and entering your password. When you're finished doing whatever (installing a lot of stuff usually does it for me), you can turn it back on at your leisure.